# easiest way to pass a url to a UIViewController that has a UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

I'm modifying some code that I've been left with and want to add some funcationality to this app. I have a table view and on the didSelectRowAtIndexPath event, I am just loading a controller that has a UIWebView. Like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc]
                                                initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
```

What I really want to do is pass in a url to load as I just have hardcoded the url to load the viewDidLoad like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = NSLocalizedString(@"WebTitle", @"");
    CGRect webFrame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    webFrame.origin.y=0;
    self.myWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:webFrame];
    self.myWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.myWebView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    self.myWebView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
    self.myWebView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.myWebView];
    [self.myWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"]]];
```

What is the easiest way to pass the url for stackoverflow.com in the instantiation of the WebViewController?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a property url in .h file then assign that property as

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];
        webViewController.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://stackoverflow.com/"];
}
```

Comment: and add the property `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSURL *url;` to that WebViewController?